# Generate an ID, Serial or Auto Increment number for child entities of a parse XML

Tags: entities, importing-exporting, feeds

I am importing several xml files with feeds tamper. Each file depic a "Contact", and using Xpath parser I am able to get child entities from each file/contact like his/her addresses.

Using entityreference autocreate it's possible to create nodes for each of these addresses, on the fly, at the same time that you import Contacts.

Problem is that xml file doesn't define an ID for these address entities so I need to generate one which will be the node title (I don't want to use the address as node title because It's too long).

I have tried with "Calculate Hash" Feeds Tamper plugin, but only generate the first address for each contact.

Also, I have tried with plugin "Setting a default value" to 0 and after this set "Mathematical operation" adding +1, but for the next iteration, value is set again to 0, not store till file end parsing, and I don't figure how to do it, maybe with Feeds Tamper PHP?